# can I develop single login form with multiple table in laravel 5.8? Please suggest

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Hope you are doing well ! I am revamping a portal there is two table of different-2 users so can I single auth form with both table? I defined guard and *provider* in **App\config\auth.php** and create model(Admin and Staff)   but user model call when I login with staff/admin. Any solution ?

**Guards**

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

     'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],



    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'staffs',
    ],


    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**providers**

```
'providers' => [

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'staffs' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Staff::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],




],
```

**Admin Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'allusers';
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

**Staff Model**

```
   <?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Staff extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'allusers';
    protected $guard = 'staff';


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

**When I login with Admin or staff user then I get**

```
**#provider: EloquentUserProvider {#214 ▼
    #hasher: HashManager {#232 ▶}
    #model: "App\User"
  }**
```

Any Solution please suggest. *Thank you*

Comment: Can you share where you are authenticating the user?

Comment: its a localhost but I can share LoginControler.php and return Auth::guard(); https://pastebin.com/5NmgGQRj

Comment: Can you share the controller please?

Comment: please check it out https://pastebin.com/qrhEeHZ4

Comment: `protected $guard = 'mission';` ?? And why use two user models, have you considered using "Roles" and "Permissions"?

Comment: Actually I have replaced that one with staff. Because Admin and staff have respective jobs and I am revamping  the portal from CI to Laravel. I have to use existing database. There is three login form so I want to merge these forms in one form.

Comment: can I define two table name in protected $table =['users_sa', 'users'] user.php (Model) ?